# API allowing to import a CSR to Microsoft CA and receive a certificate

Tags: web-services, windows-server-2012, ca, csr, certificate-authority

I need to find a way to import/submit SCR and receive a certificate from Microsoft CA via some endpoint from my server. The best option is REST, but if there is another API/protocol allowing to do a request from our server to the CA will be good enough.
Terminal utils will not work for me.

I found that there are a few options here:

1. Usage of .Net platform allowing to send/import CSR
2. CA Web Enrollment
3. CA Web Services

Our server is an on-prem solution and written on Java and may run on Windows and Unix-based platforms. It means that our customer decides what OS to use.
It means that the first option is not really an option...

The second option allows uploading an SCR to Microsoft CA via a browser, i.e. I can try to submit an HTML form and parse a response...extract the link for the cert, but it feels it is not the best option.

I found that the windows server contains the component called CA Web Services that theoretically allowing what I want, but the problem I can't find how to use it.
I followed the guidance here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831625(v=ws.11)
and Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service and Certificate Enrollment Web Service are enabled on the server.
So I have the URL and I can put it in a browser or postman:
https://.../service.svc/CES
with basic authentication but for my try I received a bad request and I couldn't find the documentation about the endpoint.

So it will be nice if someone could say to me that I'm looking in the right direction and/or send me a link to the documentation.
And if it's not the right direction, maybe someone knows a better option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are looking to generate CSR and Download Certificate from web application, please refer stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885